# Delphi FireDac DB2 DBgrid Not in edit

Tags: delphi, firedac, dbgrid

I'm migrating an old project from Delphi XE2 with BDE to Delphi 10 Seattle with Firedac. The database is IBM DB2 10.5.
After converting the source with refind.exe it correctly reset me query, database, etc. with Firedac
But I can't edit a query with cached updates in a dbgrid.
To simplify and verify I made a very simple project with FDConnection, FDQuery, FDUpdateSQL, DBGrid but I don't want to edit the grid.
Checked in the grid the various readOnly false, option dgEditing true, dgMultiselect false; in FDQuery.updateOption.enableUpdate a true but no edit

Then I simplified again leaving only the FDConnection, an FDTable and the DBGrid: in this case too I can't edit the grid (readOnly  false, dgEditing  true, dgMultiselect  false)

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried examining the individual fields in the IDE Fields editor to see if they are marked readonly?

Comment: I don't add persistent fields to my FDtable and the table is certainly not readOnly

Comment: I tried a sample application with FDConnection, FDTable, Datasource, DBGrid and a DBNavigator.

Comment: When I push the edit button on the navigator the FDTabe state turns to edit mode but I cannot write on fields in DBGrid

Comment: Well if you add a TDBEdit to your form and set it to access one on the fields in your grid,  can you edit the field's contents in the DBEdit, yes or no?

Comment: You should try to diagnose if it is a db/connection problem or a control problem. Try do edit the table by code: Edit, set some field values, Post. Does that work?

Comment: @MartynA I added a TDBEdit but cannot edit its contents

Comment: @Frazz I tried edit by code a field but received a message: "Field xxx cannot be modified". FDTAble1 has in updateOptions EnableUpdate = true but also CheckReadOnly = true. Sorry but that seems the cause. My poor knowing of Firedac has misled me

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.  I suggest you add an answer saying what you need to change to get it to work, so it could be of help to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: the problem was in FDTable1.updateOptions: the value of CheckReadOnly = true prevented the update